# Method that compares and removes all similar rows in a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, row

I'm trying to create a method that, given a table, will remove the similar rows. What i thought of doing was create a double `foreach`cycle, so that every single row in the table, will be compared to all others.

```
private void comparaeapagarowsiguais(DataTable table1)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row2 in table1.Rows)
            {
                var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                {
                    table1.Rows.Remove(row2);
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

The problem is that at some point, any given row will compare to itself, and, thus, will try to remove itself (and I would end with no rows at all). But I wanna keep at least one of every different row.

How can I cycle trough them, while avoiding any given row to be compared with herself?

EDIT: Partial solution

I've come up with a solution that works in my case. This will work if the similar rows are all immediatly next to eachother. (If you have similar rows spread around the table it won't work)

```
 private void comparalinhaseapaga(DataTable table1)
    {   //I will explain the try in the end
        try
        {
            //you will run i for as long as you like
            for (int i = 0; ; )
            {
                //you create 2 arrays from i, and i+1, this means you will compare
                //the first 2 lines of the data table
                var array1 = table1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
                var array2 = table1.Rows[i + 1].ItemArray;

                 //if they are similar, it removes row at 1, and will go back to the cycle and 
                 //proceed to compare row at 0 with the previously row at 2
                if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                {
                    table1.Rows.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    //if they are not equal, it move next to row at 1, and compare it with row at 2
                    //once it gets here, the row 0 and row 1 are already different
                    //that's why it only works when the similar rows are adjacent to another
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The try and catch are because at some point he won't have a row at position i+1 to compare, and will produce an error. Using a try/catch will skip the error and proceed, which you can do since all the similar rows are already deleted. Tested and worked ;)

Hope this is useful for someone.

Edit 2:
Found a clean solution, just take this code:

```
 private DataTable RemoveDuplicatesRecords(DataTable dt)
    {
        //Returns just unique rows
        var UniqueRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
        DataTable dt2 = UniqueRows.CopyToDataTable();
        return dt2;
    }
```

Comment: what is the goal? are you trying to achieve an array of the data type?

Comment: it's for ease of reading by the end user, he doesn't need 2 similar rows,one is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be simplified to a group by method, this can only be achieved by using linq. Then simply select the first item of each group

this will turn your datatable into an enumerable then allow you to group by the values you dont wont duplicate

```
public IEnumerable<DataRow> test(DataTable myTable)
    {
        var results = myTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(datarow => datarow .ItemArray[1]).Select(y=> y.First()) ;

        return results;
    }
```

or if its a match on all fields

```
public DataTable test(DataTable myTable)
    {
        var results = myTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct().CopyToDataTable() ;

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: I think you'r right, i created a list of the row's indexes, and tried to remove them after. But then it other problem came up. It's a rolldown of problems. I'll try to use linq and give some feedback right now

Comment: I never used linq before, can you provide more detailed information?

Comment: can you provide an example of a datarow? It's difficult with out an example

Comment: Are you being ironic? I actually laughed on it. Anyways i got the second method you posted working with my datatable. I understand that there's now some list, or array of values that correspond to each datarow, but where?

Comment: No completely misworded it, had a chuckle myself when I reread, anyways have updated my answer, it will now return a DataTable

Comment: Does it makes sense if i use, `test(onmytable);` and get exactly the same table, with all the duplicate rows? It's like, i've been reading examples, but i've never did enumerable before. If you can spare a few more minutes to this i'll be thankful

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your method adding the following check

```
private void comparaeapagarowsiguais(DataTable table1)
{
    foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row2 in table1.Rows)
        {
            if (row1 != row2) 
            {
                var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                {
                    table1.Rows.Remove(row2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, they should not be compared if is the starting row ;)

Or, you could use LINQ (like I wrote in comment) using this code to select only similar rows and then delete them:

```
private void comparaeapagarowsiguais(DataTable table1)
{
    foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
    {
        var toDelete = table1.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(row1.ItemArray));

        foreach (DataRow r in toDelete)
        {
            table1.Rows.Remove(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I'm getting System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.   This error on `foreach (DataRow row2 in table1.Rows)`  But only when i have similar rows, when i don't, the code runs fine

Comment: I think it happens because it changes the number of rows on the fly, and therefore maybe a foreach cycle is not such a great idea after all

Comment: well, if this occurs only when there are similar rows, you could put that check inside a try cactch block and delete the row if the exception is thrown (even if I don't think this is the best solution)

Comment: another solution could be to use LINQ to select row similar to the one you're checking and delete them

Comment: Tried that too, but when the code goes for the second `foreach` he will notice the number of rows has changed (because it's inside the foreach), I'm trying to work it around, but been unable too, i'm even trying to get the second `foreach` as a separate method but its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
private void comparaeapagarowsiguais(DataTable table1)
    { int a=0; int b=0;
        foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
        {  a++; 
           b=0;
            foreach (DataRow row2 in table1.Rows)
            {  b++;
                if(a!=b)
                 {
                var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                {
                    table1.Rows.Remove(row2);
                }
               } 

            }
        }


    }
```